# WP Customize refresh problem

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

Hi I am adding options to WP Customize.

Mostly everything works, but One of my variable is not refreshed in the preview window.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('checkbox', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'default' => false,
    ));

$wp_customize->add_control('checkbox_control', array(
    'settings' => 'checkbox',
    'label'    => __('Activate Coming Soon Page', 'ln'),
    'section'  => 'general_settings',
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'priority' => 1,
));
```

This is how I add the checkbox and here is my check in functions.php

```
function template_redirect() {
 if(true == get_theme_mod('checkbox')) {
        include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/coming-soon.php');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect' );
```

So everything works. ~The only problem is that the preview window when you are in WP Customize and click the checkbox it reloads the page but it doesn't shows the change. If I click save and refresh manually then everything is fine.

Any suggestion how to fix this issue?

Thank you

UPDATE:

**I found what is breaking WP CUSTOMIZER, it is the exit of the redirect. Is there another way how to fix this issue. I need to redirect to that page if the checkbox is TRUE**

```
 function template_redirect() {
     if(true == get_theme_mod('checkbox')) {
            include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/coming-soon.php');
            exit;  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'template_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 2):

A likely reason you are not able to see the change in the preview is that your `coming-soon.php` template doesn't include the requisite `wp_head()` an `wp_footer()` calls being made. If you look at your browser's DOM, you should actually see that a secondary `iframe` is getting created behind the visible `iframe`. However, if your template doesn't include the standard theme hooks then the `customize-preview.js` script won't be enqueued and it won't be able to communicate to the parent window that the `iframe` has loaded and thus is ready to replace the previous `iframe`.

This same question was actually reported to WP Core Trac in [#37981](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37981): “template_include not working in customizer previewer” in which I [answered](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37981#comment:2) similarly:

> you have to make sure that the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` calls are made so that scripts are printed. If `customize-preview.js` isn't output, then the loaded page won't be able to communicate to the parent frame that the page has finished loading. This issue actually came up recently elsewhere: https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/issues/477#issuecomment-247679386

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly adding the `'transport'` option when you call `$wp_customize->add_setting`?

e.g.

```
$wp_customize->add_control('checkbox_control', array(
    'settings' => 'checkbox',
    'label'    => __('Activate Coming Soon Page', 'ln'),
    'section'  => 'general_settings',
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'priority' => 1,
    'transport'   => 'refresh'
));
```

Alternatively, you could use a Framework to interact with the WP Theme Customizer. For example, there's a good one by Slobodan Manic call [Customizer Boilerplate](https://github.com/slobodan/WordPress-Theme-Customizer-Boilerplate). For example, to use a checkbox such as yours in Customizer Boilerplate, you would simple download the files to your theme's directory from Github, include a call in your themes `functions.php` to Customizer Boilerplate (e.g. `require( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/customizer-boilerplate/customizer.php' );` then you could modify the options provided in `options.php` to leave just the checkbox:

```
                /*
             * ==============
             * ==============
             * Checkbox field
             * ==============
             * ==============
             */
            'new_checkbox_field' => array(
                'setting_args' => array(
                    'default' => true,
                    'type' => 'option',
                    'capability' => $thsp_cbp_capability,
                    'transport' => 'refresh',
                ),                  
                'control_args' => array(
                    'label' => __( 'New checkbox field label', 'my_theme_textdomain' ),
                    'type' => 'checkbox', // Checkbox field control
                    'priority' => 2
                )
            )
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried adding 'transport' => 'refresh' but it didn't work. What I noticed is when you change the status of the checkbox the AJAX is returning the correct HTML and is changing according the option but the preview is not updated with the new response from the AJAX. I cannot understand why.

Comment: What code do you have in your theme template to get the option from the checkbox? (Please either edit/comment your original question with updated information rather than adding a new answer)

Comment: I am taking the variable with get_theme_mod()

Answer (score 0):

You should only use template_redirect when you don't want anything else hooked to template_redirect to be executed. Instead, to include an alternative template, you must use `template_include`

```
function ql_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( true == get_theme_mod( 'checkbox' ) ) {
        return TEMPLATEPATH . '/coming-soon.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_action( 'template_include', 'ql_template_include' );
```

There are other filters, like `single_template` or `archive_template`. You can find more info at the Codex
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Comment: This doesn't work for me. At least not in the customizer. If I access the page normaly it works, but if I try to access the same page within the customizer it looks like the template_include action is not recognized.